# How to access expo-file-system Filesystem.documentDirectory

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-go

I am trying to do a data backup for my React Native App with `expo go` and `expo-file-system`

```
 await Filesystem.writeAsStringAsync(
   Filesystem.documentDirectory! + "GymTracker-Data.json",
   JSON.stringify(exportData)
 )
```

How do I access this `documentDirectory` with a file explorer app like `File Manager` or `Amaze File Manager`?

I tried printing out the path on the app but I can't find said path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`documentDirectory` is your app's private internal directory, only accessible by your app. Third party apps like `File Manager` cannot access it.

At the moment, expo does not provide any API to write files to 'download' or other public directories. But this may change in future. Check these two posts discussing the issue.

https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-save-the-file-to-devices-folder-like-download/2398
https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/ability-to-save-files-on-internal-storage

Comment: What is the actual path of `documentDirectory`? I don't understand what this directory is supposed to be, or whether it exists on my phone filesystem, or whether I need to create it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **expo-sharing** library from expo together with the **expo-file-system** library.

With expo-file-system you download it to the internal private directory of your application.

and with expo-sharing you copy it to the iPhone files folder.

https://www.farhansayshi.com/post/how-to-save-files-to-a-device-folder-using-expo-and-react-native/

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/#sharingoptions

[image]

Comment: We can still read your contacts through the 90% opacity cover-up...

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me by adding these two settings in the info.plist

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

this will enable the application's public folder in the iPhone's file application

**Reference:** https://bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/

**Note**: this configuration will only work on IOS, not on Android.